# How to write regex for this javascript string

Tags: javascript, regex, split

How to write this string below

```
"(22.0796251, 82.13914120000004),36", "(22.744108, 77.73696700000005),48",...and so on
```

Like this:

```
 (22.0796251, 82.13914120000004)    36

  (22.744108, 77.73696700000005)     48
  ...and so on..................     ..
```

How to do this using regex in javscript ?

My try is this:

```
substring = test.split(',');
```

where test contains the data to be formatted. But its wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the ability of `split` to split on regular expressions and then **keep them in the results**. To do this, simply put a capturing group in the regexp. In your case, you will "split" on things in double quote marks:

```
pieces = test.split(/(".*?")/)
                     ^^^^^^^   CAPTURE GROUP

// ["", ""(22.0796251, 82.13914120000004),36"", ", ", ""(22.744108, 77.73696700000005),48"", ""]
```

The question mark is to make sure it doesn't eat up all the characters up through the last quote in the input. It makes the `*` quantifier "non-greedy".

Now get rid of the junk (empty strings and `", "`):

```
pieces = pieces . filter (function(seg) { return !/^[, ]*$/.test(seg); })

// ["(22.0796251, 82.13914120000004),36", "(22.744108, 77.73696700000005),48"]
```

Next you can break down each piece with another regexp, as in

```
arrays = pieces . map(function(piece) { return piece.match(/(.*), (.*)/).slice(1); });

// [["(22.0796251, 82.13914120000004)", "36"], ["(22.744108, 87.73696700000005)", "48"]]
```

The `slice` is to get rid of the first element of the array returned by `match`, which is the entire match and we don't need that.

Now print out `arrays`, split its elements further, or do whatever else you want with it.